Cannot convert NFA code in Algorithm course in Java to C++
I've learned Coursera Algorithm course, and I want to convert NFA code in Java of this course to C++ by myself.
Here's my code:
DirectedGraph.h:
#ifndef DIRECTEDGRAPH_H
#define DIRECTEDGRAPH_H
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <list>

class DirectedGraph {
private:
    int numVertices;
    std::vector<std::list<int>> adjacencyList;

public:
    explicit DirectedGraph(const int& numVertices);
    void addEdge(const int& source, const int& destination);
    [[nodiscard]] bool hasEdge(const int& source, const int& destination) const;
    [[nodiscard]] int getNumVertices() const;
    [[nodiscard]] const std::vector<std::list<int>>& getAdjacencyList() const;
    void printGraph() const;
};

#endif //DIRECTEDGRAPH_H

DirectedGraph.cpp:
#include "DirectedGraph.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

DirectedGraph::DirectedGraph(const int& numVertices) :
    numVertices(numVertices), adjacencyList(numVertices) {}

void DirectedGraph::addEdge(const int& source, const int& destination) {
    adjacencyList[source].push_back(destination);
}

bool DirectedGraph::hasEdge(const int& source, const int& destination) const {
    return std::ranges::any_of(adjacencyList[source],
                               [&destination](const int& neighbor) {
                                   return neighbor == destination;
                               });
}

int DirectedGraph::getNumVertices() const {
    return numVertices;
}

const std::vector<std::list<int>>& DirectedGraph::getAdjacencyList() const {
    return adjacencyList;
}

void DirectedGraph::printGraph() const {
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Vertex " << i << ":";
        for (const int& neighbor : adjacencyList[i]) {
            std::cout << " -> " << neighbor;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

DirectedDFS.h
#ifndef DIRECTEDDFS_H
#define DIRECTEDDFS_H
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include "DirectedGraph.h"

class DirectedDFS {
private:
    std::vector<bool> marked;
    int count;
    void dfs(const DirectedGraph& G, int v);

public:
    explicit DirectedDFS(const DirectedGraph& G, int s);
    explicit DirectedDFS(const DirectedGraph& G, const std::vector<int>& sources);
    [[nodiscard]] bool markedVertex(int v) const;
    [[nodiscard]] int getCount() const;
};

#endif // DIRECTEDDFS_H

DirectedDFS.cpp
#include "DirectedDFS.h"

DirectedDFS::DirectedDFS(const DirectedGraph& G, const int s) : marked(G.getNumVertices(), false), count(0) {
    dfs(G, s);
}

DirectedDFS::DirectedDFS(const DirectedGraph& G, const std::vector<int>& sources) : marked(G.getNumVertices(), false), count(0) {
    for (int v : sources) {
        if (!marked[v]) {
            dfs(G, v);
        }
    }
}

void DirectedDFS::dfs(const DirectedGraph& G, int v) {
    count++;
    marked[v] = true;
    const std::list<int>& neighbors = G.getAdjacencyList()[v];
    for (const int w : neighbors) {
        if (!marked[w]) {
            dfs(G, w);
        }
    }
}

bool DirectedDFS::markedVertex(int v) const {
    return marked[v];
}

int DirectedDFS::getCount() const {
    return count;
}

NFA.h
#ifndef NFA_H
#define NFA_H

#include "DirectedGraph.h"
#include "DirectedDFS.h"
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

class NFA {
private:
    DirectedGraph graph;
    std::string regexp;
    int m;

public:
    explicit NFA(const std::string& regexp);
    bool recognizes(const std::string& txt) const;
};

#endif // NFA_H

NFA.cpp
#include "NFA.h"
#include <stdexcept>

NFA::NFA(const std::string& regexp) : regexp(regexp), m(regexp.length()), graph(m + 1) {
    std::stack<int> ops;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        int lp = i;
        if (regexp[i] == '(' || regexp[i] == '|') {
            ops.push(i);
        } else if (regexp[i] == ')') {
            int or_op = ops.top();
            ops.pop();
            if (regexp[or_op] == '|') {
                lp = ops.top();
                ops.pop();
                graph.addEdge(lp, or_op + 1);
                graph.addEdge(or_op, i);
            } else if (regexp[or_op] == '(') {
                lp = or_op;
            } else {
                throw std::runtime_error("Invalid regular expression");
            }
        }

        if (i < m - 1 && regexp[i + 1] == '*') {
            graph.addEdge(lp, i + 1);
            graph.addEdge(i + 1, lp);
        }
        if (regexp[i] == '(' || regexp[i] == '*' || regexp[i] == ')') {
            graph.addEdge(i, i + 1);
        }
    }

    if (!ops.empty()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid regular expression");
    }
}

bool NFA::recognizes(const std::string& txt) const {
    DirectedDFS dfs(graph, 0);
    std::vector<int> pc;
    for (int v = 0; v < graph.getNumVertices(); ++v) {
        if (dfs.markedVertex(v)) {
            pc.push_back(v);
        }
    }

    for (const char c : txt) {
        if (c == '*' || c == '|' || c == '(' || c == ')') {
            throw std::runtime_error("text contains the metacharacter '" + std::string(1, c) + "'");
        }

        std::vector<int> match;
        for (int v : pc) {
            if (v == m) continue;
            if ((regexp[v] == c) || regexp[v] == '.') {
                match.push_back(v + 1);
            }
        }

        if (match.empty()) continue;

        DirectedDFS new_dfs(graph, match);
        pc.clear();
        for (int v = 0; v < graph.getNumVertices(); ++v) {
            if (new_dfs.markedVertex(v)) {
                pc.push_back(v);
            }
        }

        if (pc.empty()) return false;
    }

    for (int v : pc) {
        if (v == m) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

However, I got the following problem when I run the code:
C:\Users\kekea\Desktop\untitled\cmake-build-debug\untitled.exe
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

How can I fix this issue? I'm a newbie, so hope that somebody can help me!

You can start by learning how te debug. Set a breakpoint to trigger when a std::length_error is thrown and work your way back from there (stackwise).

Typical explanation for this is creating a vector with a negative size.

There is no need to pass integers by reference, all your const int& could be replaced wth simply int.

This is a simple debugging problem. See What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems.

OK, I'll try debugging the code, thanks!

This is too much code to read. It'd be better if you could narrow your problem to a few lines.
I start by refactoring. numVertices is totally redundant. In fact the class DirectedGraph can simply be defined  as an alais to standard classes:
#include <map>

using DirectedGraph =
      std::multimap<int,int>;

This document shows all the function and operations.
std::unordered_multimap and C++23 std::flat_multimap are other optimizations alternatives. But your main problem is ignoring a warning on NFA::NFA. In C++, class members are always constructed in declaration order and destructed in reverse. Your constructor is initializing graph from m, which is still not constructed and results in UB. You should reorder the class members:
private:
    std::string regexp;
    int m; // graph init depends on 'm'
    DirectedGraph graph;

I suggest - at least at the beginning of your C++ journey - you find the project config swith to treat warnings as error. On GCC it would be the -Werror switch, but it differs depending on build environment.
Other problems might be present in your code. This much is what I learned in short glance.

Thanks! I'm only a student self learning CS, thank you for your advice!

@Keke you dared touch C++. Learn it properly. There are important basics; If you learn them soon, C++ becomes your best friend. But skipping them leads to confusion. Most probably, you can't ask your professor about C++; he doesn't know anything. But at least you didn't rush to use pointers; that's positive approach.

You're right, it's not that easy to learn C++. Thanks for your advice!

Difficulty is finding correct channel. I cannot say it's hard to learn. There's just too much noise and bad advice. There are certain C++ idioms and rules that need attention. If you know them, you can be confident about your code. Good text covers them; bad text leaves you in oblivion to fail hard and get frustrated.
